# pkcs12 and cer relation

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

My customer has sent me tso files:

An `.cer` file and a `.p12` file.

`.p12` contains the private key and a chain of certificates.

I need to know what's `.cer` for?

Is there any way to know if `.cer` is the CA certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cer` is simply a file extension - it formally means nothing.  However, by convention, it is often used to signify an X509 certificate.

Have a look at the file with a text editor to see whether it is a Base-64 encoded file (consists of a subset of the ASCII character set) or a binary file.

If it's the former, there should be a header line such as `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` which signifies that this is a X509 certificate in [PEM format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468), which can be viewed with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in cerfile.cer
```

If it's the latter (a binary file), you can view it with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -inform DER -in certfile.cer
```

I would suggest that the `.p12` file is for the client, while the `.cer` file is for the server in order for it to be able to verify the certificate(s) sent by the client.

Comment: Let me ask you again. I'd like to know which is the purpose my customer has sent me both files, instead of only `p12` one. I mean, I guess this file is necessary for some reason I'm not able to figure out... For example, am I able to make a request with `curl` using only `p12` file?

Answer (score 0):

.cer is mostly the certificate file you requested for. CA certificate mostly have CA name in it like .cer .
You can check the same using the command :
openssl x509 -in certificate.cer -text -noout